# Why did Palermo help Gandia to escape from the hand cuffs?

Tags: money-heist

In season 4 of *Money Heist* Palermo is giving an idea to Gandia for untieing the hand cuffs.

What is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 1):

From Palermo's point of view, Tokyo has successfully led a mutiny which is currently in power. By setting Gandia loose, Palermo is **destabilizing** the mutineers.

It's established at several points, most notably by the Professor in a flashback, that Palermo stops at nothing to be in charge. This is him stopping at nothing, he'd rather compromise the heist than not lead it.

You can see the same behavior in Palermo even before he helps free Gandia. He's constantly annoying people and riling them up just to throw them off their game.

It's possible, though not proven, that Palermo was aware of the Professor's response to call a cease fire between the heist members and call for them to work together. It's reasonable that he could predict this since he is shown to be quite a people person, and on top of that he has known the Professor since childhood (since he knew Berlin since then as well, and they're brothers).

Comment: Even Tokyo herself narrates during that event that Palermo needed a distraction to seize power again, and by introducing a new danger he hoped that the rest of the gang will have to accept that they need him.